# Parsing a flattly-written nested text template into a usable nested data structure for N levels

Tags: python, html, templates, data-structures, text-parsing

I've recently been given a file intended to be used to generate HTML, a menu template of sorts and due to time constraints have gotten a python prototype working but it's brute force and works only for this case.

I know there has to be a better way to do this but my Google searches have not helped. Here's what the template files look like

```
[text](link)
[text](link)
>[text](link)
>[text](link) 
>>[text](link)
>>[text](link)
>>[text](link)
[text](link)
>[text](link)
```

I've managed to brute force this into this structure (hopefull not missing a ] or [ somewhere XD)

```
[
    [ [text](link), [] ],
    [ [text](link), [
        [ [text](link), [] ],
        [ [text](link), [
            [ [text](link), [] ],
            [ [text](link), [] ],
            [ [text](link), [] ], 
        ] ],
    ],
    [ [text](link), [
        [ [text](link), [] ],
    ] ],
]
```

But I've done this essentially by keeping track of root, parent and then checking for "", ">", or ">>" at the beginning of the line and then appending [ text, [] ] to the base for "", root for ">" and root[parent] for ">>". The problem is I want to solve for **N*>** and I'm not sure how to proceed or even what to search for. *in Python, the the answer can be in any language, Python was just the quickest to throw together*

```
menu = []
f = open('template_file', 'r')
root = 0
parent = 0
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    m = re.match('(.*)(\[.*)', line)
    if m:
        prefix = m.group(1)
        link = m.group(2)
        if prefix == "":
            menu.append([link, []])
            root += 1
            parent = 0
        elif prefix == ">":
            menu[root - 1][1].append([link, []])
            parent += 1
        elif prefix == ">>":
            menu[root - 1][1][parent - 1][1].append([link, []])
```

So this works, but it looks terrible I'm not sure what I should be searching for to find a better method of parsing those template files into these structures so I can spit out the necessary HTML. I want to prevent issues further down the line.

Much appreciated.

Comment: I've been fiddling with Haskell lately and this feels like a problem easily solved with Haskell, but I'm not quite there yet.

Answer (score 0):

Replaces each ">" with a tab.  Output is pretty much exactly as your brute force output. (file.txt is  your template file as above)

```
test = open("file.txt", "r")

for line in test:
    print line.replace(">", "\t")
    #print line
```